# Python variables cannot be defined in lamda function but could separately resolve from the function

Tags: python, lambda

- List item

Just wondering what is wrong with the code. I am trying to get the indices of "material" column that matches my searchMat criterion(a string to be exact) variable

This is my code. I have set a debugger before the code

```
pdb.set_trace()
foundCellList = wsDF['material'].loc[lambda x: x == searchMat].index
```

On running the code, it stopped at pdb.set_trace() as expected. I tried to debug the code by keying sequentially into the debugger

- wsDF['material'].loc[lambda x: x == searchMat]
- searchMat

my console readout:

```
(Pdb) wsDF['material'].loc[lambda x: x == searchMat]
*** NameError: name 'searchMat' is not defined
(Pdb) searchMat
'F383R554620000'
(Pdb)
```

Now I am at a loss of what to do

REgards

Comment: I'm guessing this is because Pandas executes the function in a different process in order to do it in parallel, and the variable `searchMat` isn't defined in that process; or something similar to that. As a workaround, you can do `lambda x, s=searchMat: x == s`, or without a lambda, `searchMat.__eq__`.